# Replacing partial with AJAX in Rails 4: undefined method `id`

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

When replacing a partial through Ajax, one method is giving me the proper result but the other (almost identical) isn't. I want to select and deselect a group for a specific campaign. Selecting gives me a direct replacement, deselecting doesn't.

*models/general_connection.rb*

```
belongs_to :campaign
belongs_to :group
```

*models/group.rb*

```
has_many :general_connections
has_many :campaigns, through: :general_connections
```

*models/campaign.rb*

```
has_many :general_connections
has_many :groups, through: :general_connections
```

*controllers/general_connection.rb*

```
def connect_group_to_campaign
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
  @campaign.general_connections.create(group: @group)
  respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js
  end
end

def disconnect_group_from_campaign
  @general_connection = GeneralConnection.where("group_id = ? AND campaign_id = ?", params[:group_id], params[:campaign_id]).first
  @group = @general_connection.group

  @general_connection.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js
  end
end
```

*views/campaign/show.html.erb*

```
<div class="row">
    <% @main_groups.each do |group| %>
        <%= render partial: 'groups_form', locals: { group: group } %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

*views/campaign/_groups_form.html.erb

```
<div class="row" id="group_<%= group.id %>">
    <div class="col m6">
        <div class="valign-wrapper black-text">
            <% if group.icon.nil? %>
                <i class="material-icons">group</i>
            <% else %>
                <i class="material-icons"><%= group.icon %></i>
            <% end %>
                &nbsp;&nbsp<%= group.title %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m6">
        <% if !grouped(group) %>                
            <%= form_tag connect_group_to_campaign_path(:group_id => group.id, :campaign_id => @campaign.id), remote: true do %>
                <%= button_tag 'check_box_outline_blank', class: "secondary-content material-icons grey-text", style: "background-color:white;border:none;" %>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <%= form_tag disconnect_group_from_campaign_path(:group_id => group.id, :campaign_id => @campaign.id), remote: true do %>
                <%= button_tag 'check_box', class: "secondary-content material-icons grey-text", style: "background-color:white;border:none;" %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

*views/general_connection/connect_group_to_campaign.js.erb*

```
$('#group_<%= @group.id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render partial: 'campaigns/groups_form', locals: {group: @group} %>');
```

*views/general_connection/disconnect_group_from_campaign.js.erb*

```
$('#group_<%= @group.id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render partial: 'campaigns/groups_form', locals: {group: @group} %>');
```

...and this is the error that I'm getting:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
12:                     </div>
13:                     <div class="col m6">
14:                         <% if !grouped(group) %>                
15:                             <%= form_tag connect_group_to_campaign_path(:group_id => group.id, :campaign_id => @campaign.id), remote: true do %>
16:                                 <%= button_tag 'check_box_outline_blank', class: "secondary-content material-icons grey-text", style: "background-color:white;border:none;" %>
17:                             <% end %>
18:                         <% else %>
```

To sum it up: both methods are working, but only `connect_group_to_campaign` gives a direct result and `disconnect_group_from_campaign` doesn't and needs a browser refresh.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `@campaign` object is not declared in `disconnect_group_from_campaign` method. Try it after adding the below line in your `disconnect_group_from_campaign` method

```
@campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
```